# Can killerbee bypass AES-128 security?

Tags: aes

I found information about KillerBee which sniffs Zigbee networks. Here is the tutorial: https://www.willhackforsushi.com/presentations/toorcon11-wright.pdf
My question, is since Zigbee Xbee can use AES-128 encryption key, and from the few I know, AES is unbreakable, how can a 40$ equipment bypass this? Am I missing something here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the slides you linked you can see that there are several methods used to **extract the encryption key**.
If the encryption key is known, AES can be decrypted!

Comment: Ok, if the encryption key is known, obviously yes. But if is not known, can an adversary found it and eavesdrop? Ok, I will look it again.

Comment: To ask it different, If I store the key on Zigbee by X-CTU, and not send it over the air. Can this be extracted?

Comment: If you never send the key over the air it can not be extracted over the air. This is why the PDF you linked also describes how to extract it from a device.

Comment: So, a solution to prevent the key extraction is what?

Comment: @just_learning don't put devices where an adversary can reach them.

Comment: How? Can you mitigate or bound electromagnetic waves??  The attacker in the described situation can proceed over the air...